# How to interpret the different cluster sizes in Silhouette plot?

Tags: clustering, python, k-means, interpretation

I created silhouette plots for my clustering models by following: [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html)

[image]

I want to know what does the different cluster sizes mean and how they were generated?? I understand that thicker size means the cluster contains more data points, but how this be generated? Are these the combination of multiple small bars or something? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Every pixel row is a point.

A cluster with 80 points is 80 pixels of silhouette values.

X-axis: silhouette value

Y-axis: points. Ordered by Silhouette and grouped by cluster